# MySQL Jar works but MSSQL does not?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I don't use the Class.forName(abcde) for my MySQL-java-jdbc code. My code works properly.
All I did was drop the `mysql.jar` in my lib folder and the code worked.

But, for MSSQL, this does not work and I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433
```

I am using both `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar`, `java 1.6` and `MSSQL 2008`.

Can you tell me how to find the cause for this problem ?

Comment: Which SQL Server driver are you using? It needs to be JDBC 4 compliant to be able to use it without Class.forName(..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got the database connection URL wrong.  There should be no `microsoft` within it.  Try `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433` instead.

See also the [MSDN documentation for the SQL Server JDBC driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx).